# Graphviz General Tree

Tags: python

I can't render the whole Tree using graphviz. I am using DFS traversal. Renderd png only consits of root and 2 children of root, while the others are missing.

```
class TreeNode:
    value: Any
    children: List['TreeNode']

    def __init__(self, value:Any)->None:
        self.value=value
        self.children=[]
```

```
def show(self):
    dot=graphviz.Digraph("Tree",format="png")

    dot.node(str(self),str(self.value))

    if len(self.children) != 0:
        for child in self.children:
            dot.node(str(child),str(child.value))
            dot.edge(str(self),str(child))
            child.show()

    dot.render(directory='doctest-output').replace('\\', '/')
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Just had to pass dot as an argument. Here's code

```
def show(self,dot=None):
    if dot is None:
        dot=graphviz.Digraph("Tree",format="png")

    dot.node(str(self),str(self.value))

    if len(self.children) != 0:
        for child in self.children:
            dot.node(str(child),str(child.value))
            dot.edge(str(self),str(child))
            child.show(dot)



    dot.render(directory='doctest-output').replace('\\', '/')
```